# Basic Cryptography Understanding: RSA signature

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, signature

I need to setup a scenario where a client sends an encrypted(AES) and signed file and the server decrypts it and verifies the signature(RSA).

Here are the steps that I thought of:

1)Compute the signature of the textfile and then append the (base64 encoded)signature into a header
2) Encrypt the textfile(with the added header).
3)Send the encrypted file to server
4)At server, decrypt the file, then extract the signature from the header(base64 decode it). Verify the sender.Then use the textfile if verified.

My question is:

Do you think I should first encrypt the textfile and then add the header(base64) in plain so that verification of sender is done first and then if sender is verified can the operation proceed to decrypt the file contents?

Bottomline is, when I did it at first, I imagined the signature can also be obfuscated and therefore I encrypted it all. Now the question is, should signatures be really obfuscated??
How does the attacker use the signature(if in plain?)? He cannot anyway tamper it as verification will fail... Please throw some light.

Comment: so the issue is whether to sign and then encrypt or some other way? [Don Davis's "Defective Sign & Encrypt in S/MIME, PKCS#7, MOSS, PEM, PGP, and XML"](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html) shows the issues with the sign and then encrypt method.

Comment: Thanks for the link :) Here is what I learn:"When a principal signs material that has already been encrypted, it should not be inferred that the principal knows the content of the message. On the other hand, it is proper to infer that the principal that signs a message and then encrypts it for privacy knows the content of the message"

Comment: If you first sign and then encrypt, and your server returns an encryption error (which is always a "bad padding" exception because there is nothing else that can go wrong) then your server is a padding oracle, and is vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. This can be avoided by adding some kind of symmetric verification, e.g. a HMAC. As this attack exposes your entire plain text message after 128 tries per byte, it is probably more important than the problem described in the link by Dan D.

Answer (score 0):

In brief: don't reinvent the wheel, especially if you don't have expertise in cryptography.

Take existing cryptography scheme, such as OpenPGP or PKI (you'll need it's CMS part) and use it. OpenPGP is good if you don't have centralized key management (i.e. no certificate authorities are involved etc). PKI is good if you want to rely on existing infrastructure of certificate (and key) distribution and management. PKI has better support in various software, but if both the client and the server are designed by you, this doesn't matter much.

Comment: thanks.Ok I shall look into OpenPGP. But leaving the implementation aside. What do you think of the encryption of signatures itself? Basically I want to know the concept better

Comment: @user489152 Dan D. posted a wonderful and worth reading answer to your question above in his comment.